# How to set vcpupin in guest xml

Tags: virtualization, openstack, libvirt

I am working with openstack and I want to pin vcpus to pcpus in guest xml. Now, the pinning operation can be done using

```
virsh vcpupin guestname vcpu pcpu
```

But I want to do it using python API. I investigated the openstack code and found out that get_guest_config function in libvirt/driver.py is responsible for generation of guest XML file. Now, I tried to put vcpupin attribute here by guest.vcpupin or guest.cputune_vcpupin but none of them is working. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Or is this functionality not available with openstack?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. You need to define the attributes in the nova.virt.config before using  them. After defining the attribute, it's working fine.